# How to test custom cordova plugin's native code?

Tags: android, cordova, unit-testing, junit, cordova-plugins

I know [cordova-plugin-test-framework](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-test-framework) will help in testing any cordova project.
I am developing a custom camera cordova plugin for Android platform. I would like to write some Junit/Instrumentation test cases for my custom camera Android plugin code.
I am facing issues as I can't create `CordovaInterface`, `CordovaWebView` Objects from my test class.

Is there anyway that I can create `CordovaInterface`, `CordovaWebView` Objects from my test class and pass these as parameters for my custom camera Android plugin `excute` method.

I would like to avoid unit test cases at js level using cordova-plugin-test-framework and write some Junit test cases (as I will have access to most of the internal classes my camera cordova plugin use). please correct me, if this wrong approach.

Comment: Any luck in finding an approach?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK No. Using cordova-plugin-test-framework only.

Comment: Ok. This is good but there is no way to find the code coverage or export the test result as report.

Answer (score 1):

First, Copy CordovaLib to your plugin project as library.
Add something like this to your Test class:

first, an activity, don't forget to add it to AndroidMainfest.xml for testing.

```
public class TestActivity extends CordovaActivity {

    CordovaWebView getWebView(){
        return this.appView;
    }
    CordovaInterface getInterface(){
        return this.cordovaInterface;
    }

    public void init(){
        super.init();
    }
}
```

In your test class:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<CordovaActivity> mActivityRule =
    new ActivityTestRule<CordovaActivity>(CordovaActivity.class);



private CordovaWebView wv;
private CordovaInterface cordovaInterface;
private YourCordovaPlugin km;
private TestActivity activity;

@Before
public void Init() throws InterruptedException {
    km = new KM1930CordovaPlugin();
    activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();

    Runnable action = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.init();
            wv =  mActivityRule.getActivity().getWebView();
            cordovaInterface = mActivityRule.getActivity().getInterface();
            km = new YourCordovaPlugin();
            km.initialize(cordovaInterface,wv);
            wv.getPluginManager().addService(new  PluginEntry("YourServiceName",km));
            synchronized (this) {
                this.notify();
            }
        }
    };
    synchronized( action ) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(action);
        action.wait() ;
    }
}
```

Then you can add your test method and call method by invoking `execute` method.

```
@Test
public void TestBluetooth() throws JSONException {
        this.km.execute("echo","[]",new CallbackContext("0",wv));
}
```

Comment: if you want to get callback result, you should make your own CordovaWebview class and override `sendPluginResult` method

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to modify a little this approach:

First of all, my `TestActivity` had to be at the same level as the activity using the `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` `intent-filter`.

Then, create the test file (in my case `MyTestActivityTest.java` **IN THE src/androidTest/java/com/your/package/name** (super important that this is an Instrumentation Test!!)

Then, on the test itself:

```
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.rule.UiThreadTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyTestActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<TestActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(TestActivity.class);

    @Rule
    public UiThreadTestRule uiThreadTestRule = new UiThreadTestRule();

    private YourPlugin mockYourPlugin;

    private CordovaWebView cordovaWebView;
    private CordovaInterface cordovaInterface;
    private TestActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Throwable {

        activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        assertNotNull(activity);

        final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1); --> this one is the important! the sync part got stucked!

        Runnable action = () -> {
            activity.init();
            cordovaWebView = mActivityRule.getActivity().getWebView();
            cordovaInterface = mActivityRule.getActivity().getInterface();
            mockYourPlugin = new YourPlugin();
            mockYourPlugin.initialize(cordovaInterface, cordovaWebView);
            cordovaWebView.getPluginManager().addService(new PluginEntry("YourServiceName", mockBankId));

            signal.countDown();// notify the count down latch, i.e release it
        };

        uiThreadTestRule.runOnUiThread(action);

        signal.await();// wait for callback
    }

    @Test
    public void TestBluetooth() throws JSONException {
        this.mockYourPlugin.execute("echo","[]",new CallbackContext("0", cordovaWebView));
    }
```

}

and my `build.gradle` file I have this dependencies:

```
// JUnit 4 framework
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
// required if you want to use Mockito for unit tests
implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'
implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.8.47'

implementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
```

and don't forget to put this also in the `build.gradle` file:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ...
}
```

I really hope this helps