# Setting up test environment for cordova android plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova plugin which is connecting to an aar library in android java. I want to perform unit testing in this plugin using JUnit or whichever is best

I am a bit confused on how to set up the test environment for this.

MyappLauncherPlugin.java

```
public class MyappLauncherPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    private static final String TAG = "MyappLauncherPlugin";

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);

        Log.d(TAG, "Initializing MyappLauncherPlugin");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        //Need to write code on receiving the intent

    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        final JSONArray methodArgs = args;
        final CallbackContext callback = callbackContext;
        final Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
        if (action.equals("set")) {
            final JSONObject queryArgs = methodArgs.getJSONObject(0);
            final String userId = "{}";
            final String userInfo = queryArgs.getString("userInfo");
            cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    launcher.setUser(userId, userInfo, cordova.getActivity(), new LauncherServerCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String response) {
                            callback.success(response);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            callback.error(t.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
        }
        else if(action.equals("launch")){
            final JSONObject queryArgs = methodArgs.getJSONObject(0);
            final String packageName = queryArgs.getString("packageName");
            final String appName = queryArgs.getString("appName");
            final String auxName = queryArgs.getString("auxName");
            cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    launcher.launchApp(appName, packageName, auxName, cordova.getActivity(), new LauncherServerCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String response) {
                            callback.success(response);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            callback.error(t.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
            });

}
```

The folder structure for this project is as

[click here](https://ibb.co/vJW8nCW)

Please help me with this.

Comment: I'm not going to mark this "duplicate" ... but please look at this thread: [How to test custom cordova plugin's native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695877/how-to-test-custom-cordova-plugins-native-code).